# Getting error testing readstream response with Jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocha.js, nestjs, chai

I am getting timeout error while testing a function that returns readStream from google cloud store.

```
// Test case
import { createResponse } from 'node-mocks-http';
it('getImage from google cloud storage', async done => {
    let res: Response = createResponse();
    let data = await controller.getImage({ image: "text data"},object, response);
});

// Function that calls google gloud storage and return object.
public async getImage(imageReqDto, baseDto, response){
    let bucket = this.storage.bucket(process.env.IMAGE_BUCKET);
    let file = bucket.file(image);
    return file.createReadStream().pipe(response);;
}
```

Any solution how to pass the test case successfully after receiving the buffer data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're testing for. If you're just wanting to make sure a ReadStream is returned, try using [`.toBeInstanceOf()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tobeinstanceofclass):

```
it('readstream is returned, when .getImage() is invoked with image data', async () => {
    const response: Response = createResponse();

    const stream = await controller.getImage({image: "text data"}, object, response);

    expect(stream).toBeInstanceOf(ReadStream)
});
```

However a better test would be to know the expected response and assert that the ReadStream matches an expected value. If it's a small image you could load into a buffer and compare. If the image is large, you may consider storing it as base64 and comparing the actual with the expected.